# How to enclose a selected string with characters?

Tags: autohotkey

Enclosing a string would be particularly useful on message boards with no markdown shortcuts, instead of typing `[quote]` `[/quote]` I could use a hotkey to do so. Adding quotation marks (") or other characters around selected text would be useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adding quotation marks (") around selected text:**

```
F1::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll   ; save the entire clipboard to the variable ClipSaved
clipboard := ""             ; empty the clipboard (start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived)
Send, ^c                    ; copy the selected text
ClipWait, 1                 ; wait for the clipboard to contain data 
if (!ErrorLevel)            ; if NOT ErrorLevel, clipwait found data on the clipboard
clipboard = "%clipboard%"   ; add the quotation marks
Sleep, 300
    Send, ^v
Sleep, 300
clipboard := ClipSaved      ; restore original clipboard
return
```

**To enclose selected text between [quote] and [/quote]**, use another hotkey and the same procedure. Just replace `clipboard = "%clipboard%"` with `clipboard = [quote]%clipboard%[/quote]` in the above code.

**For typing or pasting text between [quote] and [/quote]** use this:

```
F2:: SendInput, [quote][/quote]{Left 8}
```

Comment: You could add some additional information (e.g. execute using F1 and F2), novice users aren't necessarily able to modify the code to better suit their needs or even understand it. I'd clear the comments a bit and move some parts out of the "code box".

Comment: `F2:: SendInput, [quote][/quote]{Left 8}` script appears not to work, it replaces the selected text with `[quote][/quote]`.

Comment: This code is only for typing or pasting text between [quote] and [/quote]. To enclose selected text use the first code with another hotkey. Just replace `clipboard = "%clipboard%"` with **`clipboard = [quote]%clipboard%[/quote]`** in it.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add complete script for enclosing with "[quote][/quote]"? I understand now, but some others may not.

Comment: Do you know any other method in addition to pasting from clipboard? Some modern web forms (Xenforo) aren't compatible with the script (reproduces the selected string like this `text to copy "text to copy"`).