How to search the web via context menu with quotation marks using only mouse?
I often drag an English phrase and search it in Google or Bing with quotation marks to find the exact expression.
Dragging with the mouse, right-clicking shows me a context menu of "Search 'the phrase' in Google". Then I have to add quotation marks in the search window manually.
I believe there is a more convenient method because I have to do this hundreds of times daily.
Maybe there is a browser extension to do this, otherwise, there may be a macro.

ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Or you might write a scripts using AutoHotkey or similar tool - see https://superuser.com/questions/1218014/how-to-enclose-a-selected-string-with-characters
